# Moving a sprite forward in the direction it's facing

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'm trying to make enemy ships constantly move towards the player. Given the players X and Y co-ordinates, and the ships X and Y co-ordinates, I'm currently doing this to make the ship move towards the player:

```
Enemy.prototype.update = function(playerX, playerY) {
    // Rotate the enemy to face the player
    this.rotation = Math.atan2(this.y - playerY, this.x - playerX) - 2.35;

    // Move in the direction we're facing
    this.x += Math.sin(this.rotation) * this.speed;
    this.y -= Math.cos(this.rotation) * this.speed;
}
```

This works, however the enemies seem to circle around the player until finally colliding with them. I just want to make the enemies constantly move in a straight line towards the player.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I forget most of trigonometry, but since sin is related to y coordinates and cos is related to x coordinates, what happens if you switch sin and cos when you're updating x and y?

Comment: If I do that the enemy sprites move away from the player.

Comment: It might work if you reverse the signs as well?